# How to validate input using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am to check the number of occurrences of a numeric value in a string i.e in that string only 2 numeric characters are allowed. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+input+validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    var s ="1asds3asa"; // string to check
    var t = s.replace(/[^\d]/g,""); // a string with everything but the digits removed
    if(t.length>2)
    {
       alert("Only 2 numbers allowed");
    }
```